# Formatting number's output

Tags: c#, listbox, formatting, numbers

For example, I have a number 0,000000005 and it's displayed in ListBox like 5E-09. So, I would like it to be displayed exactly 0,000000005. Is there any way to do that? Thanx a lot.

```
listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(0.000000005));
```

Comment: **Moderator Note:** No prior effort is required for this particular question.  It's clear and reasonably scoped; if you know how to do it, then provide an answer.

Comment: **Note to OP:** You're looking for *Numeric Format Strings.*  You can find them in the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, thank you. And I'm sorry for my inattention to existing posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a format specifier, like in your case:

```
listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(String.Format("{0:F9}", 0.0000005));
```

Generic examples:

```
double v = 17688.65849;
double v2 = 0.15;
int x = 21;

Console.WriteLine("{0:F2}", v); // 17688.66
Console.WriteLine("{0:N5}", v); // 17, 688.65849
Console.WriteLine("{0:e}", v);  // 1.768866e+004
Console.WriteLine("{0:r}", v);  // 17688.65849
Console.WriteLine("{0:p}", v2); // 15.00 %
Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", x);  // 15
Console.WriteLine("{0:D12}", x);  // 000000000021
Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", 189.99); // $189.99
```

Comment: What if you don't know it is 9 digits? If it is not known in prior?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It will automaticall pad 0's. So 0.5 will become 0.500000000. Also it will automatically round if needed.

Comment: If it is greater `0.00000000000000000005`? and I don't know its length? What format I can use.? As of now I'm using "0.################" like that a long custom format? Is there a better way?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel 0.00000000000000000005 is smaller but it does not change. In this case you will see the rounded value: 0.000000000. If you want more digits you have to change the value, but in that case I would advice using the scientific format {0:e}.